# Delete files of ftp server in two or more different directories

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo on
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
@cd /d "%~dp0"
( echo open ftp.xxxxxxxx.com
echo kaxxxxx
echo kaxxxxx
echo ascii
echo cd "dir1/TUN/"
echo mdelete *.txt
echo cd -
echo cd "dir2/TUN2/"
echo mdelete *.txt 
echo bye 
)> %temp%\ftpdel.dat

ftp -i -s:%temp%/ftpdel.dat 
del /f /s /q %temp%\ftprecive.dat >nul 2>nul
```

pause

I was trying to delete all `*.txt` files of these both directories, but the script says that i can't change to `"dir2/TUN2/"`

What's wrong?

Comment: `cd -` doesn't exist on windows, does it? Sure that you are in the right dir?

Comment: I would suggest instead of `cd -`, that if `dir2/TUN2` is along side `dir1/TUN`, that you use `..` to take you up one level to `dir1`, then `..` again, something like, `cd ../..`

Comment: @Compo Worked! Thnaks

Comment: Debug your code by doing all of you script manually. Then you could have seen what the current working directory was when you tried to change to your second directory.